individual gradients with torch.autograd.grad without sum over second variable
I have a sampled path of a stochastic process starting from an initial point:

class SDE_ou_1d(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.sde_type = "into"
        self.noise_type = "diagonal"

    def f(self, t, y): #drift
        return -y

    def g(self, t, y): #vol
        return torch.ones_like(y)

t_vec = torch.linspace(0, 1, 100)  #time array
mySDE = SDE_ou_1d()

x0 = torch.zeros(1, 1, requires_grad=True).to(t_vec)
X_t = torchsde.sdeint(mySDE, x0, t_vec, method = 'euler')


and I would like to measure the gradient with respect to the initial condition using torch.autograd.grad(), and get an output with the same shape as X_t i.e. 100x1.
This gives the change in the path at every time point

X_grad = torch.autograd.grad(outputs=X_t, inputs=x0,
                           grad_outputs=torch.ones_like(X_t),
                           create_graph=False, retain_graph=True, only_inputs=True, allow_unused=True)[0]


the issue is that the gradient is a sum over all values of t.
I can do this with a for loop, but it is very slow and not practical:
X_grad_loop = torch.zeros_like(X_t)

for i in range(X_t.shape[0]):  # Loop over the first dimension of X_t which is time
    grad_i = torch.autograd.grad(outputs=X_t[i,...], inputs=x0,
                                    grad_outputs=torch.ones_like(X_t[i,...]),
                                    create_graph=False, retain_graph=True, only_inputs=True, allow_unused=True)[0]
    X_grad_loop[i,...] = grad_i


is there a way to compute this gradient with torch.autograd.grad() and no loop?
thanks

I finally found a way to make it work using jacrev mentioned.
from functorch import jacrev
    
def sample_SDE(t_vec, N_sample, x0):
    x0_per_sample = x0.unsqueeze(0).expand(N_sample, -1)
    return torchsde.sdeint(mySDE, x0_per_sample, t_vec, method = 'euler', bm = bm)

# Here we remove the N_sample dimension otherwise jacrev will think of it as another variable to differentiate through
x0 = torch.zeros(Dx, requires_grad = True).to(t_vec)

# then we differentiate
Jacob_autograd = torch.func.jacrev(sample_SDE, argnums=2)(t_vec, N_sample, x0)

in the last line, we specify that x0 (argunum 2) is the variable to differentiate with respect to.

Maybe torch.autograd.functional.jacobian is what you're looking for. Or if you want to use even "lower-level" API, functorch (which is included in Pytorch since 2023) provides you with vmap and vjp to calculate the Jacobian of the input wrt the output.
Here is some document that might be helpful:
https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.autograd.functional.jacobian.html
https://pytorch.org/functorch/stable/notebooks/jacobians_hessians.html
